# No data is being inserted into my database

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to insert data into my database using a POST request. Data is being sent to my server but when I try to INSERT it into my database it doesn't do anything. Even the console.log in the query is being sent to the console. The `req.file` is showing the right info as well.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 8000;


const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'me',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'api',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
})


app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public')
    }, 
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
    message: "Error! in image upload."
     if (!req.file) {
          console.log("No file recieved");
          message = "Error! in image upload."
          console.log("status: danger");
     } else {
        console.log('file recieved');
        console.log(req.file);

         var query = pool.query('INSERT INTO file (name, type, size) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', [req.file.filename , req.file.mimetype, req.file.size], function(err, result) {
            console.log('inserted data')
         });
         message = "Successfully uploaded";
         console.log("status: success");
     }

})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

Comment: Do you need to BEGIN and COMMIT with `pg` or does it have automatic commit if you don't supply a transaction?

Comment: @jarmod I'm not sure. I don't think I had to BEGIN and COMMIT with my other projects..

Comment: Sure, see the 1st example at https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions. Maybe it doesn't need it or maybe it automatically creates a transaction when you don't specify one, but you're still responsible for the COMMIT (maybe). The docs are pretty lacking in detail here. Add just the COMMIT and test to find out. Then add BEGIN ... COMMIT to test that.

Comment: Can you add console.log("err is",err);console.log("result is:", result) in the callback function returned from pool.query and check what is printing? That should provide you the clue, about what is happening.

Comment: @Sreehari great answer. It was giving me `error: column "name" of relation "file" does not exist`. I fixed it. Thanks.